# Javascript change variable based on variable reference

Tags: javascript

In a program i am writing i need an object variable that looks like this:

```
var map {
    cube: {__pt3arraylocation__:[0,0,0], poly: new Object()},
    other: {__pt3arraylocation__:[1,0,0], poly: new Object()}
};
```

However, i want to be able to type map.cube and have it return the **pt3arraylocation** as a default unless i specify what i want by typing map.cube.poly

for example: map.cube would return [0,0,0] and map.cube.poly would return the object poly in the object cube

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i want to be able to type map.cube and have it return the pt3arraylocation as a default unless i specify what i want by typing map.cube.poly
>
> for example: map.cube would return [0,0,0] and map.cube.poly would return the object poly in the object cube

You can't do that in JavaScript.

However, as an alternative, it's worth noting that you can add arbitrary properties to arrays if you want to. So for instance:

```
var map {
    cube:  [0,0,0],
    other: [1,0,0]
};
map.cube.poly = {};  // {} is the same as `new Object()` but not subject to people...
map.other.poly = {}; // ...overriding the `Object` symbol
```

Then `map.cube` gives you the array, and `map.cube.poly` gives you the object you've stored on that array.

How is this possible? Because in JavaScript, [arrays aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html). They're just objects that have an automatic `length` property, treat a class of property names (all numeric ones) in a special way, and have `Array.prototype` backing them up. And of course, you can add properties to any object.

There's no literal syntax for doing this, which is why I had to do it with assignments after the object initializer above. But it's perfectly valid. I use it for cross-indexing arrays all the time.

Do be sure, if you do this, that you're not using `for..in` incorrectly; [more](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this I would say is like this:

```
var map {
    cube: [0,0,0],
    other: [1,0,0]
};
map.cube.poly = new Object();
map.other.poly = new Object();
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible to achive. Maybe you can play around with toString()

```
var map = {
    cube: {
      __pt3arraylocation__:[0,0,0], 
      poly: new Object(), 
      toString : function() {
         return this.__pt3arraylocation__.toString()
      }
    },
    other: {__pt3arraylocation__:[1,0,0], poly: new Object()}
};

map.cube == '0,0,0'
map.cube.split(',') == map.cube.__pt3arraylocation__
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that exactly as you want - if you request an object (which `map.cube` is), you get an object. However, there are a few ways to do something similar.

- when used as a parameter to functions or operations that require string, like `alert(map.cube)` or `"sometext" + map.cube`, the object is converted to string by calling the `toString` function. You can therefore define, for example:

  ```
  map.cube.toString = function() { return this.__pt3arraylocation__.toString(); };
  ```
- a similar thing happens when there if the object is used in context when a number is needed. In this case, it is converted with `valueOf()`. So you can use, for example

  ```
  map.cube.valueOf = function() { return this.__pt3arraylocation__.length; };
  ```
- or you can obtain the default value via a function call, if you define your object as a function instead

  ```
  var map = {
     cube: function() {
         return map.cube.__pt3arraylocation__;
     }
  }

  map.cube.__pt3arraylocation__ = [0,0,0];
  map.cube.poly = new Object();

  alert(map.cube.__pt3arraylocation__); // 0,0,0
  alert(map.cube.poly);                 // [object Object]
  alert(map.cube());                    // same as map.cube.__pt3arraylocation__
  ```

  As you can see, in JavaScript, functions are objects like any other, so you can not only call them, but also set fields and methods to them.

Answer (score 0):

[T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) is right. Based on his answer I'd like to remark that you can also assign `map.cube` like this

```
var map = { 
             cube: function(){ 
                     var val = [0,0,0];
                     val.poly = {}; 
                     return val; }()
          };
```

Or for more values:

```
function polyval(val){
    val.poly = {}; 
    return val; 
}
var map = { 
            cube: polyval([0,0,0]),
            other: polyval([1,0,0]),
            more: polyval([1,1,0])
            /* ... etc */
};
```